# How to achieve same form select scroll bar behaviour as in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html-select

Recently it was noticed, that form select element is acting a bit differently in IE regarding scroll bar in comparison to other browsers. For example there is a select filled with years. Range is set from set year -20/+20. So from 1995 to 2035. Active value is 2015.

---

### This is how it looks in Chrome

[image]

---

### And this is how it looks in IE

[image]

---

So it is clearly visible, that in IE it tries to balance the vertical scroll bar.

Now the question is as in title mentioned. Is there anyway to detect when single `select` without `size` attribute is open and is there a way to manipulate scroll bar on such list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to control it really.

Comment: @epascarello, could you elaborate more? It did seem, that I found a solution http://output.jsbin.com/saheye/1/, but as it turned out it is only good for `select` with `size` attribute. Is it browser specific same way as for example having eye icon in password type field to see it(IE)? Or is there some(even ugly) way to achieve that on cross browser level?